# jersey-multipart: Missing dependency for method [...] at parameter at index 1

Tags: java, maven, jersey

### I tried...

I'm trying to develop my first Java application based on REST services using Jersey.

Everything worked fine when I was launching the app from IntelliJ IDEA (13.1.3), so I tried to bundle everything as a jar file with maven-assembly-plugin.

But when I launch the jar, the server isn't able to start.

```
$ java -jar target/receiver-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Jul 09, 2014 7:32:27 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init
INFORMATION: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the paths:
  target/receiver-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Jul 09, 2014 7:32:27 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFORMATION: Root resource classes found:
  class org.outofrange.receiver.FileRestService
Jul 09, 2014 7:32:27 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFORMATION: No provider classes found.
Jul 09, 2014 7:32:27 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFORMATION: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18.1 02/19/2014 03:28 AM'
Jul 09, 2014 7:32:27 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
SCHWERWIEGEND: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.outofrange.receiver.FileRestService.postFile(java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.outofrange.receiver.FileRestService.postFile(java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream), annotated with PUT of resource, class org.outofrange.receiver.FileRestService, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:172)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:246)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:92)
    at org.outofrange.receiver.ReceiverServer.<init>(ReceiverServer.java:14)
    at org.outofrange.receiver.ReceiverServer.main(ReceiverServer.java:27)
```

Basically, my `main` just starts a server with `HttpServerFactory.create("address")`, and my REST-class looks like the following:

```
package org.outofrange.receiver;

import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.*;

@Path("/file")
public class FileRestService {
    @PUT
    @Path("/{fileName}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response postFile(@PathParam("fileName") String fileId, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream) {
        return Response.ok("File successfully saved (more or less)").build();
    }
}
```

I made a [small example](https://github.com/outofrange/Receiver/tree/receiver-sscce) which should demonstrate this behaviour.

### And I tried...

If I remove the multipart/FormDataparam annotations from my rest services, the problem still occurs.
Only if I remove the dependency to jersey-multipart, I'm able to launch the packaged jar - so there has to be a problem with it.

I found many solutions to other's problems about using the same version of jersey and jersey-multipart - but according to my pom.xml (and to `mvn dependency:tree`) I'm using 1.18.1 with both of them.

Beside of that, I just found workarounds, which would be my plan B.

If I'm using jersey 1.3, I'm able to start the server from the packaged jar - the problematic versions are jersey [1.4 - 1.18.1]

- Why can I start the server with IntelliJ?
- Why can't I do it after packaging/assembling?
- How can I fix it / what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Generally if You want to run Web application you should not package it as jar file. Jar files are used for generic libraries, resources.

In this case you should package your application as war file, because you are trying to develop web application with Rest.

Please refer to: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
As far as I know, the purpose of war files is to deploy them into application servers like Tomcat; I don't want to do that. I know many stand alone Java applications (not only libraries) bundled as jar files, and it works at least with Jersey 1.3.
So I don't think the problem is with the Java archive per se.

Comment: See your point, from the exception you get in your application it looks like you did not provide Media Type for file annotated with @FormDataParam, but as I see on your java listing it is present.

Comment: I just found out that 1.18.1 isn't the newest Jersey version - it's 2.10.
After some code changes it seems to work, and I am going stick with this fix.

I won't resolve this question yet, as the problem still exists with 1.18.1

Answer (score 0):

I found out that 1.18.1 isn't the most recent version of Jersey - 2.10 is.

I've updated my dependencies from

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I had to change the creation of the HttpServer too:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(FileRestService.class);
rc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(new URI("http://localhost:9091/"), rc);
```

After changing some invalid import statements, everything just works.

Though this isn't an actual answer to my question (what's the problem with 1.18.1?), it's a solution for my problem I want to document for others.